Behavior of GAS and functions when moving folders
TOP階層ー第2階層
Aフォルダーaフォルダ内にGASや関数を含んだスプシがある場合
Bフォルダーaフォルダ内を移動した場合に既に作成しているGASや関数などは、修正が必要になりますか？
ドキュメントIDなどが変わりますか？
以上、ご教示のほどよろしくお願いいたします。
aフォルダ内をTOP階層のフォルダへ移動した場合に動作に問題が無いかご教示いただけますか。
アイテム数が40万までのためフォルダなどの細分化が必要になったが動作検証を行うユーザーが退職したため動作が分からない
TOP Hierarchy - Hierarchy 2
If there is a spushi containing GAS and functions in folder A, is it necessary to modify the GAS and functions already created if the spushi is moved in folder B?
If I move the spcies in folder B folder a, do I need to modify the GAS and functions that have already been created?
Will the document IDs, etc. change?
Thank you in advance for any guidance you may be able to provide.
If we move a folder to a folder in the TOP level, will there be any problem with the operation of the folder?
The number of items is up to 400,000, so it is necessary to subdivide the folders, etc., but the user who verifies the operation has retired, so I don't know how it works.
Translated with DeepL.com (free version)

Hi there! Please read how to ask for more information about asking good questions on StackOverflow.
